# php How to initialize the order of elements of an array after deleting

Tags: php, arrays

Please I have the following array :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_coach"]=>
    int(1)
    ["nom_coach"]=>
    string(4) "kaka"       
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_coach"]=>
    int(2)
    ["nom_coach"]=>
    string(7) "kiki"

  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_coach"]=>
    int(3)
    ["nom_coach"]=>
    string(7) "koko"

  }

}
```

After deleting array[1] I get this array :

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id_coach"]=>
        int(1)
        ["nom_coach"]=>
        string(4) "kaka"       
      }      
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id_coach"]=>
        int(3)
        ["nom_coach"]=>
        string(7) "koko"

      }

    }
```

This is normal I think, but please masters how could I do to initialize it after any delete and get instead :

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id_coach"]=>
        int(1)
        ["nom_coach"]=>
        string(4) "kaka"       
      }      
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id_coach"]=>
        int(3)
        ["nom_coach"]=>
        string(7) "koko"

      }

    }
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: [array_values()](http://php.net/array_values) ?

Comment: $cleaned = array_map('array_filter', $array_old);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_values()

```
print_r( array_values( $array ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a2=array()
foreach($array as $v){
   $a2[]=$v;
}
```

Should work.

But I have a feeling there is also a function for "normalizing" the key values.

Rereading your question, I don't think there are any way in php to force an array to always have concecutive elements (like arrays in many other programming languages does automatically) - in that aspect a php array is more similiar to a hash in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will do it.

It will return indexed array of values.

Or you could use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove the element.

```
array_splice($arr, 1, 1);
var_dump($arr);
```